# How to check when an observation is eliminated at which step from several tables in SAS

Tags: sas

I am running a program where stepwise, certain criteria eliminates records from tables.  However, a record could be eliminated after the 7th table or 8th so the way I've been doing it, merging table 1 with 2, then table 2 with 3, and so on isn't very convenient.  Is there a way I can "track" an observation with flags?  Like say, if A is in table 1 then match = 1 else match = 0.  And from there, identify which table A was eliminated from (in this case Table 3).  I would need to track possibly multiple observations (not too many, maybe 5 or 10) at a time though and they may be eliminated at different points (one in Table 3, one in Table 8).

Example:

Table 1:

Pat_ID

A

B

C

D

E

F

Table 2:

A

B

D

E

F

Table 3:

B

D

E

F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.  This merges the tables together and records which table the ID exists.

**EDIT**: In response to the question in the comments, I realize the naming can be confusing.  I'm changing the table names to make things more clear.

```
data mick;
  input PAT_ID $ ;
datalines;
A
B
C
D
E
F
;
run;

data keith;
  input PAT_ID $ ;
datalines;
A
B
D
E
F
;
run;

data ron;
  input PAT_ID $ ;
datalines;
B
D
E
F
;
run;

/* merge */
data want(drop=i);
    merge mick (in=t1) 
          keith (in=t2)
          ron (in=t3);
    by PAT_ID;
    array table[3] Mick Keith Ron;
    array t[3];

    do i=1 to 3;
        if t[i] then table[i]=1;
        else table[i]=0;
    end;
run;
```

This produces

```
PAT_ID  Mick Keith Ron
A       1    1     0
B       1    1     1
C       1    0     0
D       1    1     1
E       1    1     1
F       1    1     1
```

Comment: Thank you!  Is there a way to do this if the tables are named something completely different?  I know arrays must have sequential numbers so would the best solution to be rename them into Table 1, Table 2, etc?

Comment: Arrays do not have to be numbered columns.  You can specify the variable names in the array with `array blah[3] a b c;`.  That create array `BLAH` that references columns A, B, and C.

Comment: Updated the example with new table names to hopefully help you better understand.

Comment: You don't need the arrays or do loop.  t1, t2, and t3 are already Booleans.  You could leave your merge statement as is, and then just add:  Mick=t1; Keith=t2; Ron=t3.

Comment: @Quentin, if there are N tables, then an array is going to more compact to than to write each out.  But yes, you could do `table[i] = t[i];` inside the loop.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I got side-tracked on another project so I didn't have a chance to come back and use this for what I asked.  Thanks for updating it to help me understand.  I had to simplify the tables a bit because a couple of them had hundreds of thousands - millions of observations and the merging began to take a long time but I finally have what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When you eliminated these records, where did they go?  I co-wrote a paper a few years back that argued that any time you delete records, you should write them to a dataset of deleted records.  This makes it easier to track which records were deleted, at what step, and why.

For example:

```
data table2
     drop_missingScore
  ;
  set table1;
  if missing(score) then output drop_missingScore;
  else output table2;
run;
```

The full paper is available here: http://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug11/ds/ds06.pdf

Comment: I am running a program that others have written which doesn't do this.  As I've learned from doing a similar process on other programs, it may have been too complicated for the program writers to do this (I'm not exactly sure).  There can be instances of 6 million observations, with 3 million eliminated for a multitude of criteria.  I believe with some time and extensive coding, they could have - and it would have helped a lot indeed.  So to answer your question, I'm sort of retroactively figuring out where and why things were deleted.